# Filling a datagridview with a Web service Query

Tags: sql, web-services, inventory

I've been looking for this and I haven't succeed, I'm creating a API to update a online store inventory, using web services i can access the database with sql queries, having a table like this
    ID              STOCK
    166              1
    166              1
    172              0
    172              3
    172              2
    181              0
    181              9
    191              1

so i need the total of each id , that's when im using this SQL query:

```
sqlq= "select Id, sum(Stock) from database group by Id"  

prod = myApiClient.runQuery("webservicepage", key, sqlq, "")
```

but then the result is:

```
prod="1662172518191911"
```

but i need the result in a datagridview like this:

```
id       stock  
166        2  
172        5  
181        9  
191        1
```

I'm using visual studio 2010, but im really lost how to fill a datagridview with a webservice query.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little example from an older project, it might help you out:

```
AdminServiceSoapClient CTIData = new AdminServiceSoapClient();
CallInfo[] PhoneCalls = CTIData.GetAllCallsMadeByEmployeeOnDate(numUCID, myDte);
dataGridView1.DataSource = calls;
var Ronas = PhoneCalls.Where(c => c.CallOutcome.Trim() == "RONA").ToList();
```